# Request addition of PUT and GET to Email Filter in Admin SDK

Tags: email, filter, google-admin-sdk

We have various business needs for retrieving and modifying user email filters.

The most pressing need is when a user is on medical leave, and we're not allowed to contact the user legally.  Sometimes a forward to another account is enough, sometimes we need multiple forwards(filters) for specific purposes.  If we can't access or change the filters, this becomes very complicated, unless the user has shared their password or we are forced to change their password, locking the user out of their account.

I'm looking at https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/, which appears to state that only POST is available for email filters.  In addition, I've checked https://support.google.com/a/answer/2707558?hl=en which confirms that only one forwarding is allowed, plus filters to cover the rest.

We are requesting the addition of PUT and GET for filters so that we can control the experience with filters as we can with forwards.

Also, it appears that many others would benefit from this feature.  Searching the "Google Apps Manager's" Google Group page, this topic has come up. (but stackoverflow won't let me link it, I don't have enough "reputation yet")

Thank you in advance!

Rob

Comment: How is this question a StackOverflow question, and not a Google Admin-SDK support request?

Comment: From https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/support,

"We support the Admin SDK on Stack Overflow. Google engineers monitor and answer against the tag google-admin-sdk. You should use this tag when asking questions. We aim to answer all questions in reasonable time."